# Saving object in tag of treeview node

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to save two objects in the tag property of a treeview node?

If so, how can I do so

Thanks
bornagaindeveloper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it is possible to write a third class which has two properties pointing to your classes and save this third object to the treenode tag. You could also use the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class that has been introduced in .NET 4.0 if you don't want to write a third class yourself but I must admit that it could make your code more readable if you did.

Comment: that would mean creating the third class with two properties (one for each of the objects), instantiating the class, and saving the object.

right?

Comment: @bornagaindeveloper, yes exactly.

Comment: I know it has been a long time..but this answer was very useful

Answer (score 1):

You could store the values to array and store array in Tag.

```
node.Tag = new object[] {value1, value2};
value1_ = ((object[])node.Tag)[0];
...
```